# My output seems to be wrong in comparison to symbolab

Tags: python, math

Getting wrong output for this equation. Can someone review my code?

[image: equation]

```
from math import cos
from math import sin
from math import pi

a0 = int(input("a0:"))
b0 = int(input("b0:"))
N = int(input("N:"))
L = int(input("L:"))
X = int(input("X:"))
n = 0
an = a0
bn = b0
y=0
for i in range(N):
    an = an + 10  # since our first value would An = A0 +10 , we could just loop the values by adding 10 to it
    bn = bn * 10
    y= an * cos((n*pi*X/(L))) + bn*(sin(n*pi*X/(L)))
    print(y)
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> y= an * cos((n*pi*X/(L))) + bn*(sin(n*pi*X/(L)))
> ```

There's never any change in the *n* variable! Given that *n* starts (and remains) at 0, you always calculate
`an * cos(0) + bn * sin(0)` == `an * 1 + bn * 0` == `an`

Furthermore you need to **add** the result to the *y* variable, not just assign it. And you need to prime the *y* variable with *a0*.

```
an = a0
bn = b0
c = 0
d = pi * X / L   # precalculating for efficiency
y = a0
for i in range(N):
    an = an + 10
    bn = bn * 10
    c = c + d
    y = y + an * cos(c) + bn * sin(c)
    print(y)
```